# Cutoff energy in Quantum ESPRESSO calculation

Tags: quantum-espresso, solid-state-physics, terminology

What is cutoff energy in solid state calculations? I would just like a detailed explanation and the applicable formulas!

Comment: For the second part, I answered the equivalent VASP question here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/7273/403

Comment: Similar doc is shown in QE manual but I just want my detailed explanation and apply formulas. @ Phil Hasnip

Comment: I don't quite understand, I gave the relevant formulae in the link (equations 1 and 2). Which bit would you like me to explain more? Feel free to comment on my linked answer directly.

Comment: +1 but since Phil already answered the second question, and we have a policy of asking only one question per post, I've commented out the second question. I've added extra detail from the comments into the question body for the first question :)

Comment: I think I understood the first part of the question but thanks for Phil and Nike for the comments I think I could close this question.

Comment: I will vote to close then as per @PaulieBao